# Docker for Mac Beta: Unable to link containers properly

Tags: macos, docker, containers, docker-compose

I have tried linking two containers and executing commands valid on one from the other which works in the docker toolbox version of the tool.

Copy of YML file:

```
version: '2'

  services:

    nginx:
     image: nginx:latest
     hostname: nginx
   links:
     - php
   ports:
     - "8000:80"
   privileged: true

 php:
   image: php:5-fpm
   hostname: php
   privileged: true
```

I expect to be able to log onto the nginx container and be able to execute php i.e. php -version.

```
docker exec -it test2_nginx_1 bash

root@nginx:/# ping php
PING php (172.19.0.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.19.0.2: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.103 ms
64 bytes from 172.19.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.089 ms
```

Ping works!

```
root@nginx:/# php -version
bash: php: command not found
```

This does not work.

Logging on to the php container:

```
docker exec -it test2_php_1 bash

root@php:/var/www/html# php -version
PHP 5.6.22 (cli) (built: Jun  8 2016 17:49:08)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

Why am I not able to execute it on the linked container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why am I not able to execute it on the linked container?

Because "linking" (or, [since docker 1.10, a common network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)), is about communication, not programs.

Your `nginx` container is like an individual machine on which php was never installed. It can ping the `php` container, but not *locally* execute what is installed *only* on said `php` machine.